# Move domain to Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, dns

I registered some domains in registrar `A`, but I am not satisfied with the quality of t's service. And I want to move my domains to Azure (not only deligating domain, but full management), other words - like I bought domains in Azure. I think, this will be more easy to manage all my resources in Azure only.
I need to write a request to my registrar `A` with full name of new registrar and set ids.

1. Is it possible to move domains to Azure?
2. Where I can get Azure registrar ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the comments here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/, as of today it is not possible to move domains to Azure. What you could do is move domain to other registrar and make use of [`Azure DNS Service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/dns-overview/) for DNS hosting of your domains in Azure.